# Diagnose Google security warning?

Tags: google, google-apps

I have received the following from Google:

> Critical security alert
>
> Suspicious attempt to sign in with your password
>
> Google prevented someone who knows your password from signing in to your account. If this wasn’t you, you should change your password immediately.

As this wasn't me (I don't think) I'm slightly concerned as this has happened a couple of times. Google has blocked it but is there any way of finding out who or where the attack occurred? When you view the alert it doesn't tell you what or who has triggered it which is rather unhelpful! I'd just like to be able to debug the details to see what is going on.

Furthermore after additional research, nothing appears after "If this wasn’t you, you should change your password immediately." and "Were you recently prevented from signing in to your Google Account?". The picture here https://ifunny.co/meme/security-activity-critical-security-alert-yesterday-pm-suspicious-sign-in-WBqYQmuT8 shows the actual user info (which is blank for me) so I'm wondering if its almost a false negative. Without the details of *who* has logged in I think Google typically include them?? Lots of people on the web reporting IP addresses etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll the the very bottom of gmail you should see the following link:

[image: Details]

This should allow you to see the account activity for the last few days:

[image: Account Activity]

Out of an abundance of caution, I would most likely open a new `Incognito window` (clears cache, and forces new session ID), log into your gmail account by manually typing the address `gmail.com`, and changing your password.  You should also change the passwords of any other sites that make use of this password (but we all know you didn't reuse that password on multiple sites ... )

Comment: Thanks for this. I did find the Details button during my research but the problem was the alert was "an hour ago" but nothing was listed. Additionally Google listed my server IP 6 address as registered in China (its in the UK) as I do use the password/account to send emails from my websites. So I was hoping to see something which tied in with the timestamp but I didn't.